# Downloading always current data in R?

Tags: r, download

I would like to download the data from this website https://www.pse.pl/dane-systemowe/funkcjonowanie-kse/raporty-dobowe-z-pracy-kse/generacja-zrodel-wiatrowych. Except for I need to have it always for the last 7 days and the table on the website contains only the data for the current date. In order to have it for a period I need to manually click "Eksport za okres" and select the period. I don't know how to access it for the current date - 7 days.

Below is what I have tried, I would prefer to stick to the R standard package, dplyr or ggplot2 if possible.

```
library("rvest")

#reading content of the page
url <- "https://www.pse.pl/dane-systemowe/funkcjonowanie-kse/raporty-dobowe-z-pracy-kse/generacja-zrodel-wiatrowych"
html <- read_html(url)

#selecting table and extracting data
table <- html_nodes(html, "table")
data <- html_table(table)
data <- as.data.frame(data)

#filtering date
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% filter(Date >= as.Date(Sys.Date() - 7))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That CSV export URL includes start and end dates. Note that there's still an issue with header encoding. While the correct encoding seems to be *windows-1250*, `read.csv2()` works only with *latin1*, table itself should be OK, but few chars in the header are probably not what you'd expect. Tibbles in output are just for more decent formatting, other than that it's just base R.

```r
today <- Sys.Date()
csv_url <- paste0(
  "https://www.pse.pl/getcsv/-/export/csv/PL_GEN_WIATR/data_od/",
  format(today-7, "%Y%m%d"),"/data_do/", 
  format(today, "%Y%m%d"))
df <- read.csv2(csv_url, colClasses = c("Date", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"), encoding = "latin1")
```

Result:

```r
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    190 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Data                             : Date, format: "2022-12-12" "2022-12-12" ...
#>  $ Godzina                          : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ Generacja.Ÿróde..wiatrowych      : num  2303 2285 2529 2868 3188 ...
#>  $ Generacja.Ÿróde..fotowoltaicznych: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...

head(tibble::as_tibble(df))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Data       Godzina Generacja.Ÿróde..wiatrowych Generacja.Ÿróde..fotowoltaicz…¹
#>   <date>       <dbl>                       <dbl>                           <dbl>
#> 1 2022-12-12       1                       2303.                               0
#> 2 2022-12-12       2                       2285.                               0
#> 3 2022-12-12       3                       2529.                               0
#> 4 2022-12-12       4                       2868.                               0
#> 5 2022-12-12       5                       3188.                               0
#> 6 2022-12-12       6                       3505.                               0
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​Generacja.Ÿróde..fotowoltaicznych

# ...

tail(tibble::as_tibble(df))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Data       Godzina Generacja.Ÿróde..wiatrowych Generacja.Ÿróde..fotowoltaicz…¹
#>   <date>       <dbl>                       <dbl>                           <dbl>
#> 1 2022-12-19      17                       5502.                               0
#> 2 2022-12-19      18                       5384.                               0
#> 3 2022-12-19      19                       5246.                               0
#> 4 2022-12-19      20                       5199.                               0
#> 5 2022-12-19      21                       5282.                               0
#> 6 2022-12-19      22                       5283.                               0
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​Generacja.Ÿróde..fotowoltaicznych
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>